# Pointer to Function Return

Tags: c, function, pointers, syntax

Assume the following function prototype:

`void *function(int arg)`.

Is that a pointer to a function? If so, how can this return a value, if it's return type is void? The description of the function says that it may return a positive integer or NULL. Since these are two different "types", would that be the reason it's `void`? To avoid typecasting?

Comment: It can't return a positive integer. It returns a pointer (which might be the NULL pointer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a pointer to a function. It says that it returns a void pointer. The advantage of a function returning a `void *` is that you can cast it to any type in the function. See [here](http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/programming/node87.html) for an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not a pointer to a function. It's a function that returns `void *`, also known as a generic pointer.

A pointer to a function that returns `void` would be this:

```
void (*function)(int arg);
```

And **that** function wouldn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a pointer to a function; it's a function that returns a pointer to `void`: i.e., an undifferentiated pointer to raw memory.  A pointer to a function returning void would be `void (*function)(int arg)` -- those parentheses change the meaning entirely.

Answer (score 0):

```
void *function(int arg);
```

is not a pointer to a function. It is the prototype of a function that returns a `void *` and has an `int` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's a prototype specifying that the function `function` takes a single `int` argument and returns a `void *` value.

A pointer to a function would look like this:

```
void *(*fn)(int arg);
```

This creates a pointer `fn` which points to a function matching the properties of `function`.